# Cannot access Swift Framework in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c-blocks, swift-framework

Create Swift Framework ,

Geolens.swift

[image]

When i am trying to access in Objective-C project , cannot call 2 methods

`createuser` & `startSessionForUser`

[image]

Getting error like this

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

[image: Getting error adding @objc]

Comment: Please, **do not** include code as screenshots. Paste code as text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `errorCode: Int?` in `UserCompletionBlock`.

`Int` is `value type`, and `Objective C` cannot represent `Optional` of `value type`, only `reference types` such as `class` will.

So you have to either:

1. get rid of optionality
2. use reference type, such as `NSNumber` or your own wrapper
3. drop this parameter completely

Answer (score 0):

Add `@objc`:

```
@objc public func createUser(...) { ... }
@objc public func startSessionForUser(...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the methods to be accessible in Obj-C also please make sure you add `@objc public` in definition of all the methods. Just the way you did it in `didRegister...` and `didFailedToRegisrer...` methods in your class.

Happy Coding...